# How to georeference HDF5 file with missing or wrong metadata

Tags: coordinate-system, georeferencing, hdf5

I'm trying to access data in a HDF5 file. I can access the data itself but the metadata, in particular the information to georeference the information, is still a problem. I had [partial success](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/389906/how-to-convert-from-hdf5-to-geotiff-with-python) in this regard. But the projection claimed in the metadata has to be wrong, because this is data for the Netherlands, not the North pole. I have contacted the provider pointing this out, but they have ignored my point, just briefly answering me with a suggestion to check [the product documentation](https://www.knmidata.nl/data-services/knmi-producten-overzicht/radar-producten/data-product-1) (which I translate with Google Translator).

In the documentation, they just mention two pieces of information regarding georeference:

- the size of the image in pixels (which is trivial)
- each pixel is 1 km x 1 km
- they give the coordinates of the four corners of the image

They do not mention the projection nor any affine transform. Am I missing something? Is this information sufficient to georeference this data? I think not, but I might be misunderstanding this.

Using `QGIS` I have put these four points in a map and they do not line-up:

[image]

Well, the problem is that I do not know the projection. I have tried Mercator (the one used to take this snapshot), some conic and an stereographic (common for radar information). But they still do not line up. Something I find very odd that the points have so different latitudes. I would expect these points to form something very similar to a square, but it seems to be rotated.

Is it possible to georeference this data with the sparse information given in the documentation? It seems currently impossible, and I do not think the providers will help me any further.